# Enterprise Search web service in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, search, mapping, metadata, moss2007enterprisesearch

I have a question to Enterprise Search in SharePoint. I use this functionality over web service (.../_vti_bin/search.asmx). There are some standart set of attributes (Name, Title...) returned as search result. For more attributes I created new "Metadata Property Mappings" and started full crawl, to be sure attributes in index will be updated. So here my questions:

1. Some of the attributes are in search results empty (for example property mapped on ows_BaseName). Is it a security issue?
2. I need uniquely identify object returned from search (to this time only files). So I want to use ows_GUID, because I need to get more informations from list service about this object. But I can't find property ows_GUID in list of properties in "Metadata Property Mappings". Can I map any property?
3. Actually if I could map all properties in "Metadata Property Mappings", I didn't need to use extra call on List web service. But if I can't, how can I uniquely identify object returned from search service to query a List service?

Regards

Anton Kalcik

Answer (score 0):

I know one thing for sure, ows_Guid can't be used, call it a bug. The last one not sure what you mean.

Comment: Hi! What I mean with question 3 is, that if can't use some properties (ows_Guid) what for other way is to identify object. When I want call List web service to ask for some more informations about this object, I need some uniquely identifier. GUID will be excellent. I tried to use URL, but I don't have a success (List web service returns property error).